# elasticsearch fuzziness setting in Meteorjs

Tags: meteor, elasticsearch

I use ElasticSearch for my Meteor app. [elasticsearch-river-mongodb](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb) hooks ES and MongoDB together.

The regular full-text search works as expected via below code:

```
    var result = Meteor.http.get(url, {
        params: {
            q: q,               
            fields: '_id,feed_category,summary,title,description,author',
            from: from, // offset into results (defaults to 0)
            size: size // number of results to return (defaults to 10)
        }
    });
```

I'd like to support fuzzy search, I tried:

```
var result = Meteor.http.get(url, {
    params: {
        fuzzy: q,               
        fields: '_id,feed_category,summary,title,description,author',
        from: from, // offset into results (defaults to 0)
        size: size // number of results to return (defaults to 10)
    }
});
```

It doesn't return the correct result, and it always has 36 hits.

I then tried:

```
var result = Meteor.http.get(url, {
    params: {
        "fuzzy_like_this" : {
            "fields" : ["_id", "summary", "title", "description", "author"],
            "like_text" : q,
            "max_query_terms" : 12
        },
        from: from,
        size:size
    }
});
```

Same as above, doesn't return correct result, and always has 36 hits.

How do I configure the parameters for ES fuzziness in Meteor?